# Submitting JSON list of elements to MVC 5 controller result in null pointer exception

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

Backend I have a controller like this this:

```
public class MixSearch
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int um { get; set; }
    public string search { get; set; }
}

public class JsonPostMixSearch
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public MixSearch[] elems { get; set; }
}

public class MixController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Best(JsonPostMixSearch mixsearch)
    {
        List<Mix> mixes = new List<Mix>();
        Mix lowest = new Mix { Products = new List<Product>(), Total = 0 };
        mixes.Add(lowest);

        List<List<Product>> matrix = new List<List<Product>>();
        foreach (var product in mixsearch.elems)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            foreach (var term in product.search.Split(' '))
            {
                var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(term)).OrderBy(p => p.Price/p.Quantity).Take(4).ToList();
                products.AddRange(query);
                lowest.Products.Add(query.First());
                lowest.Total += query.First().Price * product.quantity;
            }
            matrix.Add(products);
        }

        return View(mixes);
    }
}
```

Frontend I use jquery to create the proper data from previous added elements in page:

```
    $("#calcolamix").click(function (e) {
        var mix = new Object();
        $(".productsearch").each(function (index) {
            var input = $(this);
            mix[index] = { quantity: input.data("quantity"), um: input.data("um"), search: input.data("search") }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Best","Mix")",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(mix),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (response) {
                $("#mixresult").html(response.responseText);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#mixresult").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Request payload is the following

```
{0: {quantity: 1, um: 1, search: "acqua"}}
```

Now, i tried many different combinations but still I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  at the following lines

```
    foreach (var product in mixsearch.elems)
```

It is quite obvious that the controller does not deserialize properly the payload, the problem is can't understand how to submit list of objects using jquery and JSON.

Anybody can shed a light on this?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have things matched up correctly. In your c# object, MixSearch is an array, but your request payload has the 'MixSearch' part as an object. Is the index coming through correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserialization doesn't work, because the model binder in ASP.NET MVC cannot map the incoming data to the `JsonPostMixSearch` type. You should create an array inside the `mix` object named `elems` and add the elements to that array. Also, you should set the `index` property on `mix` too:

```
var mix = {};
mix.elems = [];
$(".productsearch").each(function (i) {
        var input = $(this);
        mix.index = i;
        mix.elems[i] = { quantity: input.data("quantity"), um: input.data("um"), search: input.data("search") }
    });
```

Comment: It worked properly, thx! honestly I was wondering whether is there any way to get something more streamlined removing JsonPostMixSearch and just put somenting like List<MixSearch>. any clue?

Comment: Try something like this: In JavaScript you simply declare an array variable: `var mixSearchList = [];` And in the each function, you add elements to it: `mixSearchList[i] = { quantity : .... }` In your AJAX call, you send this array to the action method: `data: JSON.stringify(mixSearchList)`. In your action method modify the signature like this: `public ActionResult Best(List<MixSearch> mixSearchList)`.